# How to add pagination to XMLAGG query result in Oracle?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle12c

I have a SQL query returning XML data similar to the following example:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("Columns", 
  XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("Column", CNAME) ORDER BY CNAME)) AS DATA
FROM Col
```

Now I would like to add pagination support to that query. As the XMLAGG function merges all elements into one XML result the standard "WHERE ROWNUM < 100" approach will not work.

How can I add pagination to Oracle SQL queries containing XMLAGG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paginate in a sub-query and then do the aggregation in the outer query:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("Columns", 
       XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("Column", CNAME) ORDER BY CNAME)) AS DATA
FROM   (
  SELECT CNAME
  FROM   Col
  ORDER BY CNAME
  OFFSET 0 ROWS
  FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
);
```

Comment: Is it optional to repeat the ORDER BY within XMLAGG or is it mandatory?

Comment: @blerontin You can try it yourself and see whether Oracle raises an exception - however, on the brief test I did, it worked without it.

Comment: You may [omit](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm) it, but it is mandatory if you need a guaranateed element order.